# The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches the origin from the positive

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Please, assist me with limit of the following:

Suppose that $f(x)=e^{-1/x}$ and the higher order derivatives are given by
$$\displaystyle{f^{(n)}(x)=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\frac{a_k}{x^k}\right)e^{-1/x}}.$$
Then, show that 
$$\displaystyle{\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}f^{(n)}(x)=0}.$$

Comment: @Sulaynab Perhaps that you meant$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f^{(n)}(x)=0$$

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that exponential $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x}$ decreases faster that any power of 1/x increases for $x \to 0^+$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Substitute $-\frac 1x$ by $t$ and note that $x\to0^+\iff t\to-\infty$.

Comment: Do you mean $t\to \infty$?

Comment: @BrazilianCérebro I meant to write $-\frac1x$, not $\frac1x$. I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: prove that

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^k}=0$$

for all $k\in\Bbb N$.